# I get question marks whenever I try to list netsh interface names on cmd

Tags: networking, router, cmd.exe, wireless-router

Running windows 10 on a TOSHIBA for work. I am trying to manually set a specific MTU for my Wi-Fi, but whenever I try to run `netsh int ipv4 set subinterface "Wi-Fi" mtu=1480 store=persistent`, I get the following back: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

I figured that the name for the wifi interface is something other than what I put in the parameter, so I run `netsh interface show interface` and I get the following:

`Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Hamachi
Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        ????????? ??????
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        ?????? Wi-Fi
Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        ??Ethernet
```

So I try to run set MTU once again with the same command-line, copy-pasting the interface name of my Wi-Fi (which I don't know why it comes out as question marks). However, I get the same error saying it's incorrect.

How do I solve this? thanks for reading.

Comment: What language pack do you have installed

Comment: You mean what language my machine is on? Well, it first came in Libyan Arabic but I removed it and installed US & UK English

Comment: Ok, that’s why. Remove or rename the adapters.

Comment: Thank you. How exactly do I do that? What command do I use?

Comment: I tried the following: `netsh interface set interface name="?????? Wi-Fi" newname="Wi-Fi"`
Pressed enter, it comes back with: `No more data is available.`

Comment: I would either rename the adapter through File Explorer or uninstall the adapter and reinstall it. Stop using a console to solve a problem caused by the differences between English and Arabic or at the very least stop using command prompt and use Windows Terminal or PowerShell

Comment: Note that the question marks are not litterally question marks, but other characters that your system cannot display. as such your netsh command won't be able to find an interface named "?????? Wi-Fi" because that is not actually the name of an interface on the system.

Comment: You might be able to delete the interfaces or rename the by editing their respective keys contained within **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces** any specific help will require some additional information

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I managed to change the adapter's name from the control panel. All is well.

Comment: @WreckTime - You should submit a detailed answer so you can help others with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You could always use powershell commands for it. The below command will show each interface with an 'f' in the name, then update the jumbo packet assignment.

```
 get-netadapter | where-object { $_.Name -like "*f*"} | foreach-object { Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name $_.Name -RegistryKeyword '*JumboPacket' -RegistryValue 1450 }
```

If you have any issues you can verify the properties that exist and their associated values with this.

```
get-netadapter | where-object { $_.Name -like "*f*"} | foreach-object { get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name $_.Name }
```